# How to get current postition of video stopped in chewie controller in time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using chewie controller in my app, I need to get duration of video the user watched i.e., where the user stopped watching the video in time.

Answer (score 3):

You could for instance do:

```
chewieController.videoPlayerController.position
```

That returns a `Future<Duration>`

or just use the videoPlayerController object, that you used to construct the chewieController, directly.

Comment: How can I use that would you please tell me, I am new to flutter.